# Insert PHP functions in a variable

Tags: php, function, mixing

I need to insert

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["marke"])) { echo "?marke="; echo $_GET["marke"]; echo "&farbe=gelb"; } else { echo "?farbe=gelb"; } ?>
```

into a variable.

But of course

```
<?php
$var = if (isset($_GET["marke"])) { echo "?marke="; echo $_GET["marke"]; echo "&farbe=gelb"; } else { echo "?farbe=gelb"; }
?>

 <?php
echo $var;
?>
```

isn't working ^^ What would the right Code look like?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "insert <source code> into a variable." What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: i'm about to do it :D

Comment: i need to wait 8 minutes to vote fot the right comments

Comment: `if()` is not a function and has no return value. You can **NOT** do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a function; just use the *ternary operator*.

```
$var = (isset($_GET["marke"])) ? "?marke=" . $_GET["marke"] . "&farbe=gelb" : "?farbe=gelb";
```

Comment: I don't see a function... but `echo` is not necessary when setting a variable.

Comment: The title of the question mentions "inserting a function in a variable." And I'm not echoing anything in this sample...

Comment: Oh, gotcha -- I see "function" in the title. You're suggesting that asking for a function is misguided. Regarding `echo`, I was referring to the OP's use of `echo`, not yours.

Comment: Not sure the title having "function" in it is relevant considering the overall understanding of the basic syntax. ie, they may not actually want function

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the var and concatenate the strings:

```
$var = "?";
if (isset($_GET["marke"])) {
    $var .= "marke=" . $_GET["marke"] . "&";
}
$var .= "farbe=gelb";
```

And then:

```
echo $var;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to set data to a variable if GET is set, and if not set to something else, use this:

```
if (isset($_GET["marke"])) 
  {
    $var = "?marke=".$_GET['marke']."&farbe=gelb";
  }
else
  {
    $var = "?farbe=gelb";
  }
```

But remember to validate GET data before using it with mysql etc, to make sure it's what you allow.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you want to save the output into a variable, and then do something before outputting the variable again, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
$var = if (isset($_GET["marke"])) { echo "?marke="; echo $_GET["marke"]; echo "&farbe=gelb"; } else { echo "?farbe=gelb"; 

echo <<<_END
<html>
//write something here
</html>
_END;

echo $var;
?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That code doesn't appear to be valid in its current form.

Comment: Edited the code and appended a ; at the end of _END

Comment: https://eval.in/49380

Comment: Yeah a ternary operator would've been a smarter, more rational approach.

I assumed that the question was for whether he could maintain the variable's content after the closing tag, and use the same variable somewhere else on the page.